# In React, when calling "useState" and destructuring the returned array, how does "count" get updated when calling "setCount"?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the React example:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#reading-state

I am not as much interested in React, I am curious about this pattern, and whether it is a React specific behavior:

```js
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

Because if this is not a React thing, I am clearly missing something about how JavaScript works.

Could I somehow easily implement the above patter without React?

```js
function useState(value) {

  /*
    Some vanilla JS
  */

  return [
    getState(),
    setState,
  ]
}

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

As far as I understand, `count` is a primitive data type, and in this case, it gets its value by copying the first item of the array useState returns.

I don't see how `count` could be updated by calling setCount - without something React may do under the hood.

If the destructured `count` was an object, I could see how an updated value could be referenced as `count.value`. But in a react app, we can reference `count` to get a most recent value.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The setter function results in the whole outer function call running again, resulting in a new call to `useState`, which returns the updated value in the first array item. See linked question for an example implementation of how it works.

Comment: Is this question more about the react component lifecycle than it is about [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)? Just think of "state" as being a "bin" to store values, they can be primitives, or they can be objects. React uses shallow object equality to reconcile state updates and rerender. The hook abstracts a bit of this "bin" away and is simply returning the value that was stored in it.

Comment: [this](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) is an illuminating article about how `useState` is implemented

Comment: @CertainPerformance
Thank your for the overall idea. I have a question about the example implementation. Isn't the "state" array expected to hold multiple items here, instead of always just one? Also, doesn't the closureStateIndex always remains 0 in this example? - because when App is called, it is always reset to 0, stateIndex++ doesn't seem to have an effect here. Thank you.

Comment: In the linked answer, the `state` array is intended to be an array for which each item corresponds to a `useState` call. If it's only called once in a given component, it'll only have a single item. If it's called multiple times in a component, it'll have that many items, each corresponding to the current state of that variable in the component.

Comment: Yeah, `closureStateIndex` is always 0 in that snippet, but if the `myFunction` (that is, the `setState`) is called again, it'll be the index of the call as ordered in the component. First call of `myFunction` will have a state variable corresponding to `state[0]`, `closureStateIndex` of 0. Second call of `myFunction` will have a state variable corresponding to `state[1]`, `closureStateIndex` of 1.

Comment: @CertainPerformance
I call it a second time, like for example:  `if (myValue === 'newValue') { updaterFunc('newest'); }`. The index does not change, and the state array's length is always 1. What is updated is that single value at index 0, and this is what is always referenced. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: There's a new item in the state array for each call of `useState` or `myFunction` in the function body. Eg `const [myValue, updaterFunc] = myFunction('initialValue');
  const [myValue2, updaterFunc2] = myFunction('initialValue');` - 2 calls of `myFunction` makes for 2 items in the state array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Could you maybe update the example to show multiple calls? - if it isn't too much trouble.

Comment: I guess, see edit

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok, I think I misunderstood how it is supposed to work.